# Install Gecko and Photoshop on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, wine, photoshop

I have wine and winetricks installed on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS

```
wine --version
wine-1.7.30

winetricks --version
20140302
```

I'm trying to install Photoshop CS6 on my Ubuntu using wine.

When I run this command:

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```

Why I still getting Gecko install error?

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
Executing w_do_call atmlib
atmlib already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call gdiplus
gdiplus already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call msxml3
msxml3 already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call msxml6
msxml6 already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call vcrun2005
vcrun2005 already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call vcrun2005
vcrun2005 already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call vcrun2008
vcrun2008 already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call ie6
ie6 already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call fontsmooth=rgb
Executing load_fontsmooth rgb
Setting font smoothing to rgb
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_fontsmooth=rgb\fontsmooth.reg
Executing w_do_call gecko
Executing load_gecko
------------------------------------------------------
Please install gecko in /usr/share/wine per http://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko.  http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-gecko.sh is an easy script to do that.  Then you should never need to do 'winetricks gecko' again.
------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the result of ls -l on /usr/share/wine:

```
ls -l /usr/share/wine
total 224
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov 10 11:14 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov 10 11:14 gecko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6118 Nov  5 15:03 l_intl.nls
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov 10 11:14 mono
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 204267 Nov  5 15:03 wine.inf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    648 Jan 17  2012 wineserver-restart-required.update-notifier
```

and this is the result of ls -l on /usr/share/wine/gecko:

```
ls -l /usr/share/wine/gecko/
total 109220
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sasan sasan 14732288 Nov  9  2011 wine_gecko-1.4-x86.msi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sasan sasan 16995328 Jul 18  2012 wine_gecko-1.7-x86.msi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sasan sasan 17774592 Oct  9  2012 wine_gecko-1.8-x86.msi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sasan sasan 19060224 Jan  9  2013 wine_gecko-1.9-x86.msi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  20871680 May 29  2013 wine_gecko-2.21-x86.msi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  22373888 Sep 28  2013 wine_gecko-2.24-x86.msi
```

Comment: Try [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/)

Comment: Is there any way to fix wine issue?

Comment: I have no idea! i haven't fixed anything wine related in ages. PlayOnLinux, handles that for me.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. Error is still there but photoshop is installed and working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) supports [Adobe Photoshop cs6](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html).

Install PlayOnLinux like so:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

After the POL installation has finished, click on `install` and, search for `Adobe Photoshop cs6`, click install, and follow the setup wizard.

From the [Adobe PhotoShop cs6 support page](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html):

> NOTE: This application does NOT work on Intel graphics (at least not
>   that I have seen). Nvidia and AMD graphics should be used.